# Running Web Server in File (file://) protocol

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using Quasar to make an Vue SPA web app/page. In this case, this web app should be ran only by clicking the index.html file, which is created by Quasar packager. The package will only be distributed locally and will NOT be hosted in a domain.

Now my question is. Since I will be using `XMLHttpRequest` to open local files in the bundle (xml files), I need to open a web server.

Is there any way I can auto-start (programatically) a web server just by double-clicking on the `index.html` (`file://` protocol)?

I was thinking something like this (but I still couldn't get it to work due to error `Cannot statically analyse 'require(…, …)' in line 74`):

```js
const LocalWebServer = require('local-web-server')
const ws = LocalWebServer.create({
  port: 9000,
  directory: 'public'
})

/* shut down */
ws.server.close()
```

https://github.com/lwsjs/local-web-server/wiki/API-reference

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, a html file will not be able to launch an executable and open a tcp port.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it should be possible to make a Quasar PWA working from a USB key if you make all your data static and calls to it local.

Basically you’re looking at creating a snapshot, or several snapshots of all of the api calls made by your app. Which means, if your API can request « products », you need to export them all in a .json so you can perform « queries » locally, to a global object.

This means all of your axios requests (which are XMLHttpRequests sugar-coated anyway) or equivalents must be replaced by static data, for example: file://[some_path_of_your_choice]/products.json, categories.json, anything_the_app_requires.json, etc.

Then any « by id » request the app makes, i.e. « show product detail page, which id is in the current file:/// URL », the app fetches the ID in the global objects you’re going to declare, once you’ve stringified the .json files mentioned above.

1. .json files are accessed through file:/// (path is relative to index.html)
2. You turn them into global JS objects (all views may need access).
3. (optional) you initialize them in $state (if the app requires state management)
4. don’t worry too much about performance bottlenecks, except the browser ones.
5. You may have to concatenate all of your vue files into a single one.